# pwa on chrome mobile keeps returning only cached version of data http responses

Tags: angular, caching, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, mobile-chrome

I have an Angular 7 Progressive Web Application (PWA, Service Worker).

My app is makes http requests to an api to get data for the page. with the service worker I cache the data so that the next time a user enters the page he will see the cached data until he/she gets the latest data from the http response.

The problem is in Chrome Mobile on Android. It keeps returning only the cached http response and not the new data. Every other browser and os are returning the new data.

Here is my ngsw.json file:

```
{
  "configVersion": 1,
  "timestamp": 1553131016147,
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "urls": [
        "/favicon.ico",
        "/index.html",
        "/main.888b10bbc9ea06b8a9bf.js",
        "/polyfills.9f595158f842acad6b37.js",
        "/runtime.2f29e12616932f0ed037.js",
        "/styles.d2478451b17ed7e705c5.css"
      ],
      "patterns": []
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "urls": [],
      "patterns": [
        "https:\\/\\/maxcdn\\.bootstrapcdn\\.com\\/font-awesome\\/4\\.7\\.0\\/css\\/font-awesome\\.min\\.css"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "dataGroups": [
    {
      "name": "api",
      "patterns": [
        "\\/api"
      ],
      "strategy": "freshness",
      "maxSize": 100,
      "maxAge": 259200000,
      "timeoutMs": 5000,
      "version": 1
    }
  ],
  "hashTable": {
    "/favicon.ico": "7c6a9b4e1370b6ee9386e16fba9ca4738b9e7037",
    "/index.html": "fdf70f70c0f37aaa11b990ac0cf32839480b69a4",
    "/main.888b10bbc9ea06b8a9bf.js": "abcc804a2ffbd57187d759a7c18b82963ac03d8c",
    "/polyfills.9f595158f842acad6b37.js": "4eb96258211620bfe371478144b69844117f5120",
    "/runtime.2f29e12616932f0ed037.js": "21109b3561b5a6c3ed51bc3015962f05da8e57b3",
    "/styles.d2478451b17ed7e705c5.css": "29fb80dd9fc36fbb4ee107f15fd24dd7400ea255"
  },
  "navigationUrls": [
    {
      "positive": true,
      "regex": "^\\/.*$"
    },
    {
      "positive": false,
      "regex": "^\\/(?:.+\\/)?[^/]*\\.[^/]*$"
    },
    {
      "positive": false,
      "regex": "^\\/(?:.+\\/)?[^/]*__[^/]*$"
    },
    {
      "positive": false,
      "regex": "^\\/(?:.+\\/)?[^/]*__[^/]*\\/.*$"
    }
  ]
}
```

The relevant code part is under dataGroups, all urls with `/api` prefix, and as you can see I am using `freshness` strategy, which according to Angular's Service worker configuration page:
https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config

> freshness optimizes for currency of data, preferentially fetching
>   requested data from the network. Only if the network times out,
>   according to timeout, does the request fall back to the cache. This is
>   useful for resources that change frequently; for example, account
>   balances.

but it seems the opposite happens in this case of Chrome Mobile on Android.

Did any of you encounter this and can point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

From What I understand about how angular service workers work is:

If you have specified a `freshness` strategy then the service worker will wait for the time specified with the `timeout` key (not timeoutMs) for the network to respond if the network doesn't respond within time specified the response will be sent from the cached data by the service worker.

In your case, the android device may be having less internet speed so the data doesn't get fetched within the specified timeout interval, so you get the cached data. Check the App by increasing the timeout.

---

*Just in case you need this.*

I found caching API requests very unreliable, I didn't have a clear idea when will I get the updated data for sure. (Yes when the maxSize or maxAge exceeds the specified values or the timeout has exceeded, but still no clear way in which I could get the fresh data for sure.).

Whenever I wanted to get the fresh data from the server, I cleared all then cached data from the browser which belonged to `ngsw` api calls. I had this script written for the same. Have a look if you need it.

```
caches.keys().then((keys) => {
    keys.forEach((eachCacheName) => {
        let regExPat = /^(ngsw).*api.*/;
        if (regExPat.test(eachCacheName)) {
            caches.open(eachCacheName).then((eachCache) => {
                eachCache.keys().then((requests) => {
                    requests.forEach((eachRequest) => { eachCache.delete(eachRequest); });
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: the current timeout I use is 5 seconds, and the average http response time i'm getting for the api calls is 250ms which is way under 5 seconds... and also the page finishes loading with the cached data in less than 1 second, it doesn't seem to wait 5 seconds for anything.

Comment: @shahaf Okay, I just had some hinge and it was only a guess. I don't know what could be causing this. Try opening the browser in incognito mode and see if there is any improvement.